# How to automatically generate linking dashes to labels in math equations

Tags: equations, formatting

[image]

```
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ %
\documentclass[english]{book}
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ %
%
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath} %
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb} %
\usepackage{tikz} % tikz - essential
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %
\usepackage{newtxtext} %
\usepackage{newtxmath} %
\usepackage{xcolor} %
\usepackage{colortbl} % changed to just colortbl
\usepackage[paperwidth=170mm,paperheight=240mm,textwidth=132mm,lmargin=12.5mm,rmargin=12.5mm,bindingoffset=12.5mm,noheadfoot,nomarginpar,showframe,showcrop]{geometry} %
\usepackage[a4,frame,cam,center]{crop} 
\usepackage{setspace}
%
% --------------------------------------- START DECLARATIONS --------------------------- %
%
\setlength{\unitlength}{1mm} % 1mm=2.834646pt; 1pt=0.3515mm
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt}

\newenvironment{eq}[2]{ %
  \setlength{\mathindent}{#1}%
  \setlength{\hsize}{\dimexpr\hsize-#2\relax} %
  \ignorespaces
}{\ignorespacesafterend}

\renewcommand{\theequation}{\hspace{1.0pt}\thechapter\hspace{0.7pt}.\hspace{0.7pt}\arabic{equation}\hspace{0.8pt}}


\begin{document}

\setstretch{1.00}
\noindent Using the latest 64-bit versions of Technic Center and MiKTeX 2.9\hspace{2.2pt}\ldots

\noindent How can I automatically generate the sequences of dashes within the equations so that \\ they line up perfectly left-to-right.

\vspace{-12pt}
\begin{eq}{124pt}{18pt}
\begin{equation}
\text{\hspace{2pt}}l\hspace{-0.4pt}+\hspace{-0.4pt}m\hspace{-0.4pt}=\hspace{-0.4pt}m\hspace{-0.4pt}+\hspace{-0.4pt}l\text{\hspace{12pt}-\hspace{6pt}manually developed spaces \hspace{8pt}-\hspace{10pt}} \label{eqn:chap_intro_to_num_02}
\end{equation}
\end{eq}

\vspace{-12pt}
\begin{eq}{106pt}{18pt}
\begin{equation}
\text{\hspace{2pt}}(\hspace{1.0pt}l\hspace{-0.4pt}+\hspace{-0.4pt}m\hspace{-0.4pt})\hspace{-0.4pt}+\hspace{-0.4pt}n\hspace{-0.4pt}=\hspace{-0.4pt}l+\hspace{-0.4pt}(\hspace{0.4pt}m\hspace{-0.4pt}+\hspace{-0.4pt}n\hspace{0.8pt})\text{\hspace{24pt}-\hspace{22pt}-\hspace{22pt}-\hspace{22pt}-\hspace{22pt}-\hspace{12pt}} \label{eqn:chap_intro_to_num_04}
\end{equation}
\end{eq}

\vspace{-12pt}
\begin{eq}{78pt}{18pt}
\begin{equation}
x\hspace{0.6pt}+\hspace{0.6pt}x\hspace{0.6pt}+\hspace{0.6pt}x\hspace{0.6pt}+\hspace{0.6pt}x\hspace{0.6pt}+\hspace{0.6pt}x\hspace{0.6pt}+\hspace{0.6pt}x\hspace{0.6pt}+\hspace{0.6pt}x\hspace{0.6pt}+\hspace{0.6pt}x\hspace{0.6pt}+\hspace{0.6pt}x\hspace{0.6pt}+\hspace{0.6pt}x=12x\text{\hspace{14pt}-\hspace{22pt}-\hspace{22pt}-\hspace{22pt}-\hspace{12pt}} \label{eqn:chap_intro_to_num_06}
\end{equation}
\end{eq}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: ??? why all the `\hspace` ??

Comment: note that `\newenvironment{eq}[2]{ %` and  `\setlength{\hsize}{\dimexpr\hsize-#2\relax} %`  the `%`  has no effect and you still get spurious space tokens if you leave a space before the `%`

Comment: `\setlength{\unitlength}{1mm} % 1mm=2.834646pt;`  This comment is wrong (with tex pt) 1mm=2.84526pt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly you can use `\leaders`  You could use `\dotfill` but that uses dots, but it is easy to make a similar command using a dash.

[image]

```
\documentclass[english]{book}
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ %
%
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath} %
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb} %
\usepackage{tikz} % tikz - essential
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %
\usepackage{newtxtext} %
\usepackage{newtxmath} %
\usepackage{xcolor} %
\usepackage{colortbl} % changed to just colortbl
\usepackage[paperwidth=170mm,paperheight=240mm,textwidth=132mm,lmargin=12.5mm,rmargin=12.5mm,bindingoffset=12.5mm,noheadfoot,nomarginpar,showframe,showcrop]{geometry} %
\usepackage[a4,frame,cam,center]{crop} 
\usepackage{setspace}
%
% --------------------------------------- START DECLARATIONS --------------------------- %
%
\setlength{\unitlength}{1mm} % 1mm=2.834646pt; 1pt=0.3515mm 
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\newenvironment{eq}[2]{%
  \setlength{\mathindent}{#1}%
  \setlength{\hsize}{\dimexpr\hsize-#2\relax}%
  \ignorespaces
}{\ignorespacesafterend}

\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thechapter.\arabic{equation}}

\newcommand\dashfill{\leaders\hbox to 1em{\hss--\hss}\hskip\fill\kern0pt\relax}
\begin{document}


Using the latest 64-bit versions of Technic Center and MiKTeX 2.9\hspace{2.2pt}\ldots

How can I automatically generate the sequences of dashes within the equations so that \\ they line up perfectly left-to-right.


\begin{eq}{124pt}{18pt}
\begin{equation}
l+m=m+l \dashfill \label{eqn:chap_intro_to_num_02}
\end{equation}
\end{eq}

\begin{eq}{106pt}{18pt}
\begin{equation}
(l+m)+n=l+(m+n)\dashfill \label{eqn:chap_intro_to_num_04}
\end{equation}
\end{eq}

\begin{eq}{78pt}{18pt}
\begin{equation}
x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x=12x\dashfill \label{eqn:chap_intro_to_num_06}
\end{equation}
\end{eq}

\end{document}
```

Comment: it isn't clear why this example is using left aligned equations and then indenting to look centred, but that's how it was in the question.

Comment: I understood the option fleqn signified only that the numbering would be on the right.

Comment: Your solution is just what I wanted.

Comment: @keith77777 `fleqn` has no effect on the position of the label, it is "flush left equations" that is have equations  flush to the left margin rather than the default centred layout. Your `eq` env is very odd, as they are flush left with manually specified indent?

Comment: With numbering necessarily present (whether right or left), centring in the literal sense can never give an aesthetically pleasing result; hence the indent.  Regarding the eq environment...  it was given to me as part of an answer by Stack Exchange some time ago; can it be dispensed with?

Comment: @keith77777 I can't tell you whether it can be dispensed with or not you give no indication of its intention. The markup seems odd to say the least (where do the numbers come from?) Certainly I have never seen anyone mark up equations that way in 30 years of tex use.

Comment: David The newenvironment "eq" happens to be declared here above.  Its purpose was to indent the equation numbers a prescribed distance from the right.  Should I ask a new question?

Comment: @keith77777 yes I can see its definition, but there is no text to say what is the intention of it.  As I said in the answer you are left aligning all equations and then (somehow, by eye??)  indenting them individually to make  each one look almost centred, that isn't really a feasible mechanism for any document with more than a couple of equations. (Not to mention all the hspace in the original question which i removed in this answer.)

Comment: Carlise Yes, as of now, it has to be done "by eye", but I personally think it is worth the effort.  Would you be kind enough to modify the line \dashfill{\leaders\hbox to 1em{\hss--\hss}\hskip\fill\kern0pt\relax} so that the leading and trailing spaces can be controlled (reduced): that is {here -  -  -  -  - and here}(5.2)

Comment: I can't  imagine any journal editor allowing this kind of markup (it makes it impossible to change fonts for example) but in a private document it is OK I suppose but vastly complicates the markup and at best you can get the centering that you would get automatically  with the normal markup. on the dashes, just change the `1em` to whatever width you want to control the space around the dashes.